# VS code, writing extension that plots a graph

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ide, vscode-extensions

Frustrated that there is no extension to do something I want I am writing my own. One of the key features I need is to be able to display graphs within vs code itself (graph refers to both a curve and nodes-edges).

In order to accomplish this I learnt about [webviews](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview), but that seems overkill. All I need is some very basic draw functionalities (straight line, bezier curve, circle, text).

The minimum I need to be able to do is:

I have code that generates a list of values over time. All the extension needs to do is read the generated txt file and plot the evolution of the values over time. Ideally this happens in the sidebar.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webviews are the way to go. You can do things like this with them:

[image]

See also my [antlr4-vscode extension repo](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4)

Comment: How did you make that first diagram? It;s beautiful

Comment: This is one of the possible D3.js graphs. Check the gallery for many more ideas: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery